# Cannot give length variable to crop package?

Tags: lengths, crop

I don't understand why, but the following code fails with the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \myStock 
l.607 \AtBeginDocument
                      {\@nameuse{CROP@init@\CROP@driver}}
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \myStock 
l.607 \AtBeginDocument
                      {\@nameuse{CROP@init@\CROP@driver}}
```

while if I use `\newcommand` instead of `\setlength`, it works great.

Any idea why I can't feed the `crop` package with length variable, while it works with the geometry package?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\myWidth}\setlength{\myWidth}{297mm}
% Does not work
\newlength{\myStock}\setlength{\myStock}{302mm}
% Works
% \newcommand{\myStock}{302mm}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=\myWidth,
  paperheight=\myWidth,
  pdftex=false,dvips=false,vtex=false,
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=\myStock,height=\myStock,center,pdflatex,frame,noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}%
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expanded form of the lengths registers works:

```
\newlength{\myWidth}\setlength{\myWidth}{297mm}
\newlength{\myStock}\setlength{\myStock}{302mm}
...
\usepackage[width=\the\myStock,height=\the\myStock,center,pdflatex,frame,noinfo]{crop}
```

Then the value of the options `width` and `height` is `859.27322pt` instead of the length register.

Comment: Thanks, then is there any advantages of using length instead of newcommand?

Comment: @tobiasBora It depends on the usage. I do not see much benefit as option for package `crop`. An advantage can be, if the length is used in calculations.